# Change the drop down on particular data select

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, html, jquery-mobile

In below if condition there are few id (id="store_id")on which i need both master and salve in below drop down option(id="store_machine"). else only master . Am using switch case  where that particular id will come then both thing master and salve should come ,except that only master

```
<tr>
    <td>
        <b>Store ID</b>
        <br>
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="number"  id="store_id" readonly>
        <br>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <b>Machine</b>
        <br>
    </td>
    <td>
        <select name="select-native-3" id="store_machine" data-iconpos="left">
            <option value="Master">Master</option> 
            <option value="Slave">Slave</option>
        </select>
        <br>
    </td>
</tr>




    <script>

    $(function() {

    $('#store_id').on('change', function() {
      $('#store_machine').empty();


      switch($(this).val()) {


 case "1425427806":
          $('#store_machine')
            .append($('<option value=""></option>'))
            .append($('<option value="Master">Master</option>'));
                .append($('<option value="Slave">Slave</option>'));

          break;

case "1452469394":
          $('#store_machine')
            .append($('<option value=""></option>'))
            .append($('<option value="Master">Master</option>'));
                .append($('<option value="Slave">Slave</option>'));

          break;

case "1489455419":
          $('#store_machine')
            .append($('<option value=""></option>'))
            .append($('<option value="Master">Master</option>'));
                .append($('<option value="Slave">Slave</option>'));

          break;

case "1415643163":
          $('#store_machine')
            .append($('<option value=""></option>'))
            .append($('<option value="Master">Master</option>'));
                .append($('<option value="Slave">Slave</option>'));

          break;
    }

 default:
             $('#store_machine')

              .append($('<option value="">Select Machine</option>'))


            .append($('<option value="Master">Master</option>'));


}};


    </script>
```

I need help where am going wrong .Thanks

Comment: Again you post a superficial question with no try/error code. You need to explain yourself better in the question details.

Comment: check [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I have tried through script not working...through switch case

Comment: Check your switch syntax and remove the readonly from the number input field to test it. https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp You'll find your errors using the dev tools in chrome or firefox.